# NodeJs or Java for Data Analytics?

Tags: java, node.js, elasticsearch, data-analysis

I have to do analysis of data that would be about **50** *TB*. I have been searching for few time but still confused which to use?

While searching I came across few points about node that it supports less *computation service*, *numerical analysis* and can be used for *samller data set*.
**Is it true?**

We have to design complex algorithms for statistics and display the result in web browser.
We will be using logstash and elastic search for filtering and storing data.

So which language would be the better choice. *Java or Node*?

Comment: Python and R (and a [few others](http://www.fastcompany.com/3030716/the-9-best-languages-for-crunching-data)) would be better suited for working on that amount of data

Comment: @Val we need to make a web server that could also be scalable and can handle other information regarding users.

Comment: I think elastic search better for searching. elasticsearch is npm  module in node js.We use this searching flipkart data

Comment: @HimanshuGoyal we will be using elasticSearch as a database. But for interacting with the browser we need to define the server that would be able to handle the request for users and design algorithms for data analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely Java. This kind of thing is Java's domain. [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/), [Elastisearch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elasticsearch), [Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/core/), [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/), [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) are all written in Java. [Spark](http://spark.apache.org/) and [Storm](http://storm.apache.org/) also run on the Java Virtual Machine. If you intend to use any of these tools, Java would be a first-class language.

Node may be useful in implementing the server side of the front end to enable designers to use JavaScript on both the client and server side. But, as far as web server speed and scalability is concerned, according to the [tech empower benchmarks](https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/), Java is faster too.